# An error ocurred while starting the kernel Python in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I updated Python to version 4.2 with Anaconda Navigator. I am kind of new to programming, but I have an error in the console. It says "An error ocurred while starting the kernel" and than the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\anass\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Users\anass\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\anass\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py", line 23, in 
start.main()
File "C:\Users\anass\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 253, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\Users\anass\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 43, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\Users\anass\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 31, in 
from spyder_kernels.customize.spyderpdb import SpyderPdb
File "C:\Users\anass\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 23, in
from IPython.core.inputtransformer2 import TransformerManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.core.inputtransformer2'
```

What should I do to fix this?
When I open Spyder, it says (Python 3.6). Is that maybe part of the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Please open the Anaconda Prompt and run there

`conda update anaconda`

`conda install ipython=7.6.0`

That should fix your problem.